# Unit Test Custom AuthenticationHandler Middleware

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

How do you unit test custom middleware that inherits from `AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>`?

My custom class that inherits from it is for Basic authentication.

```
    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IProvidePrincipal _principalProvider;

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, IProvidePrincipal principalProvider)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _principalProvider = principalProvider;
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.Authorization, out StringValues authorizationHeader))
            {
                if (Credentials.TryParse(authorizationHeader, out Credentials credentials))
                {
                    var principal = await _principalProvider.GetClaimsPrincipalAsync(credentials.Username, credentials.Password, Scheme.Name);

                    if (principal != null)
                    {
                        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

                        return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Basic authentication failed.  Invalid username and password.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Basic authentication failed.  Unable to parse username and password.");
                }
            }

            return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Basic authentication failed.  Authorization header is missing.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Unit testing custom middleware is relatively easy, but when you inherit from `AuthenticationHandler`, the base class throws a wrench in it.  After looking everywhere and only finding integration tests, I was finally able to figure out how to do it.

Basic setup of the unit test that won't change per test.

```
    [TestClass]
    public class BasicAuthenticationTests
    {
        private readonly Mock<IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>> _options;
        private readonly Mock<ILoggerFactory> _loggerFactory;
        private readonly Mock<UrlEncoder> _encoder;
        private readonly Mock<ISystemClock> _clock;
        private readonly Mock<IProvidePrincipal> _principalProvider;
        private readonly BasicAuthenticationHandler _handler;

        public BasicAuthenticationTests()
        {
            _options = new Mock<IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>>();
            
            // This Setup is required for .NET Core 3.1 onwards.
            _options
                .Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(new AuthenticationSchemeOptions());
            
            var logger = new Mock<ILogger<BasicAuthenticationHandler>>();
            _loggerFactory = new Mock<ILoggerFactory>();
            _loggerFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(logger.Object);

            _encoder = new Mock<UrlEncoder>();
            _clock = new Mock<ISystemClock>();
            _principalProvider = new Mock<IProvidePrincipal>();

            _handler = new BasicAuthenticationHandler(_options.Object, _loggerFactory.Object, _encoder.Object, _clock.Object, _principalProvider.Object);
        }
```

**Special note** on `_loggerFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<String>())).Returns(logger.Object);`
If you do not do this, your unit tests will bomb after your handler finishes on a null reference in code that you cannot debug.  It is because the base class calls `CreateLogger` in its constructor.

Now, you can setup the context using `DefaultHttpContext` to test the logic.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task HandleAuthenticateAsync_NoAuthorizationHeader_ReturnsAuthenticateResultFail()
        {
            var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

            await _handler.InitializeAsync(new AuthenticationScheme(BasicAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName, null, typeof(BasicAuthenticationHandler)), context);
            var result = await _handler.AuthenticateAsync();

            Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);
            Assert.AreEqual("Basic authentication failed.  Authorization header is missing.", result.Failure.Message);
        }
```

**Note** that you cannot call `HandleAuthenticateAsync` directly as it is protected. The handler must be Initialized first then call `AuthenticateAsync`.

I included the rest of the logic to be tested below to give examples on how to manipulate the context
and assert on the result for different testing scenarios.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task HandleAuthenticateAsync_CredentialsTryParseFails_ReturnsAuthenticateResultFail()
        {
            var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var authorizationHeader = new StringValues(String.Empty);
            context.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Authorization, authorizationHeader);

            await _handler.InitializeAsync(new AuthenticationScheme(BasicAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName, null, typeof(BasicAuthenticationHandler)), context);
            var result = await _handler.AuthenticateAsync();

            Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);
            Assert.AreEqual("Basic authentication failed.  Unable to parse username and password.", result.Failure.Message);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task HandleAuthenticateAsync_PrincipalIsNull_ReturnsAuthenticateResultFail()
        {
            _principalProvider.Setup(m => m.GetClaimsPrincipalAsync(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>())).ReturnsAsync((ClaimsPrincipal)null);

            var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var authorizationHeader = new StringValues("Basic VGVzdFVzZXJOYW1lOlRlc3RQYXNzd29yZA==");
            context.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Authorization, authorizationHeader);

            await _handler.InitializeAsync(new AuthenticationScheme(BasicAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName, null, typeof(BasicAuthenticationHandler)), context);
            var result = await _handler.AuthenticateAsync();

            Assert.IsFalse(result.Succeeded);
            Assert.AreEqual("Basic authentication failed.  Invalid username and password.", result.Failure.Message);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task HandleAuthenticateAsync_PrincipalIsNull_ReturnsAuthenticateResultSuccessWithPrincipalInTicket()
        {
            var username = "TestUserName";
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username) };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, BasicAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName);
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            _principalProvider.Setup(m => m.GetClaimsPrincipalAsync(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>())).ReturnsAsync(claimsPrincipal);

            var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var authorizationHeader = new StringValues("Basic VGVzdFVzZXJOYW1lOlRlc3RQYXNzd29yZA==");
            context.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Authorization, authorizationHeader);

            await _handler.InitializeAsync(new AuthenticationScheme(BasicAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName, null, typeof(BasicAuthenticationHandler)), context);
            var result = await _handler.AuthenticateAsync();

            Assert.IsTrue(result.Succeeded);
            Assert.AreEqual(BasicAuthenticationHandler.SchemeName, result.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
            Assert.AreEqual(username, result.Ticket.Principal.Identity.Name);
        }
```

Comment: note that `_options` must return `new AuthenticationSchemeOptions()` when `OptionsMonitor.Get(Scheme.Name)` is called in `InitializeAsync`. When using NSubtitute, I had to explicitely say so (otherwise the test crashed)

Comment: @Luk I had to do the same thing for NSubstitute for it not to crash. But I'm not sure I understand why given this line: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/AuthenticationHandler.cs#L85   - it should just create a new instance itself? What am I missing?   As an aside - I only had to do this in .NET Core 3.1 (I migrated an app from 2.1 where this didn't matter).

Comment: Thank you @Luk, you have solved a mystery for me that I got when upgrading from 2.2 to 3.1 and again when creating a new 3.1 project. As @Travis pointed out I couldn't see why on earth this would be an issue given that line in the code for `InitializeAsync` and until I read your comment I had been completely unable to work it out.

Comment: To avoid Null reference exception with Authentication 3.1 library , add on line number 2 in BasicAuthenticationTests() constructor following line

 _options.Setup(x => x.Get(AuthenticationSchemeOptions.AuthenticationSchemeName)).Returns(new AuthenticationSchemeOptions());